# Where should I set up or host my email server?

Tags: email, hosting, cloud

Currently, I use google apps for email at my domain. I don't feel comfortable with Google having access to my email logs.

What is the best way to do this? I was thinking about setting up an instance on Amazon EC2, but I have heard that their IP Addresses are blacklisted by spam filters. Rackspace Cloud has the same issues.

Where should I host my email server?

Answer (score 2):

What is the volume of your email? Currently there are solutions such as [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/), or [Amazon's Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) which do not require you to have an Amazon instance. If I recall, they have some free plans too. (Sendgrid has 200 email credits for the free plan).

Either way, I think you should save your time to host your own email server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seconded. Here is a complete list of the better players in the space: PostageApp (mine!), SendGrid, Amazon SES, PostmarkApp, Critsend, and Mad Mimi. Take your pick and try to figure out which one suits your needs.